# Angular UI Bootstrap unable to get textbox value to controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to get the value of search_name which is entered in the textbox by the user. Can anyone point out the mistake.

```
 <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
  <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <uib-accordion-group heading="Search">
        <p class="form-group">
            <label>Search Name</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="search_name" class="form-control">
        </p>
        {{search_name}}</br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="Myfunc()">Search</button>
        <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped"   fixed-table-headers="scrollable-area">
            <dir-pagination-controls max-size="5" direction-links="true" boundary-links="false" > </dir-pagination-controls>
                <tr>
                    <td>Index </td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>ID</td>
                </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in names "  >
                    <td>{{ $index + 1 }} </td>
                    <td>{{ x.NAME }}</td>
                    <td>{{ x.ID }}</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </uib-accordion-group>
  </uib-accordion>
</div>
<script type="application/javascript">  
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;
  $scope.names= {0:{'NAME':'John','ID':'albania'}}; 

  $scope.Myfunc = function() {
    console.log($scope.search_name)
    console.log($scope.names)
  };
```

When I log the value it says undefined.

Comment: you need to pass the value like, ng-click="Myfunc(search_name)"

Comment: @ Afroza Yasmin Are you sure ? Still I tried and it did not work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass search_name into your controller function.  This requires 2 changes.

**Controller**

```
  $scope.Myfunc = function(search_name) {
    console.log(search_name);
    console.log($scope.names);
  };
```

**HTML**

```
    ng-click="Myfunc(search_name)"
```

Answer (score 0):

did you change $scope.Myfunc = function() to $scope.Myfunc = function(search_name) ?